# Please help me identify this brake pad type

Tags: brakes

What is the proper name for this type of brake pad?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: The distinguishing point is that it is a rim brake pad with a female-threaded insert to accept a male screw, vs the usual male stud.  I've seen these on a few high-end bikes, and they are a PITA to find replacements for (when digging around in our buckets of used parts).

Comment: These are standard on road bikes since at least 90s and widely available in bike shops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a rim brake pad for road bikes, with separate holder and rubber insert, Shimano/SRAM style.

Comment: Thanks for that - is there a type/brand you would recommend?

Comment: In my experience Kool Stop Salmon and the cheapest basic Jagwire have been good. The rubber insert is replaceable, you don't need to replace the holder.

Comment: Thanks for that - exactly the type I'm after! Now to find them in the UK!